# Latest mobile Chorme session bug?

Tags: session

new chrome version is 42.0.2311.108, it updated 3 days ago.
Since that, when I open my website, close it, and reopen it again I recognized don't I have new session id, but the latest refreshed.

I checked in other browsers but at reopening I allways get new session.

I think it's a bug. Or not?
Could someone check this problem?

Comment: Try to clear the session & cache in Settings. If still can't, reset the Chrome.

Comment: I've already done it and removed and reinstall it.